# Why using past perfect tense in "some scientists had noted .."

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

While I was reading this [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/business-32743770), I  wondered Why using past perfect tense in

> some scientists **had noted** a decline in skills and numbers of students
>   applying to read Computer Science.

I have checked the following [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52006/why-use-the-past-perfect-tense-perfect-aspect-instead-of-the-simple-past-tense) which seems very similar to my question, and the answer of that question is great, But the answerer adopt on *main point* and *time points* happened before that *main point*. But I can't understand where is the main point in what I was read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article goes on to say that this noting of decline in skills resulted in the Raspberry Foundation. So it's the older past event that explains the more recent past event.

> Eben Upton, Alan Mycroft, and four other academics at the University
>   of Cambridge's Computer Laboratory *had noted* a decline in skills and
>   numbers of students applying to read Computer Science. ...
>   **So the sextet *founded* the Raspberry Foundation as a charity to revive Britain's garage-geek spirit.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using Past Perfect *(had noted)* in the cited context is simply that it's talking about something that [had already] happened before the time referenced in the "main point" of the passage.

> *[some researchers] **had noted** [something]...*
>    *[more background context]*
>    *So [those researchers] **founded** the Raspberry Foundation*

It would have been perfectly acceptable to report the earlier act of *noting* using Simple Past *(they noted something)*, but stylistically the Past Perfect helps to underlines the fact that the passage is *telling a story* that unfolded over time in a logical *and* temporal sequence.